# FactoryGirl association duplicate key error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, factory-bot

What is the correct way to assign associations that already exist?

I am trying to assign a has_one relationship between a user and a city, where the same city can be used by many users or other entities (e.g. an event).

**Code**

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :user do
    name  'john'

    trait :in_boston do
      association   :city, factory: :boston
    end
  end
end
```

**Error**

PG::UniqueViolation: ERROR:  duplicate key value violates unique constraint "city_pkey" because it's trying to create Boston twice in the database.

What I would like to do is simply reference the existing factory, not create a new one.

**My current working (but less than ideal) solution**

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :user do
    name  'john'

    trait :in_boston do
      after(:create) do |user|
        user.city = City.find_by_name('Boston') || create(:boston)
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Any guidance would be appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

So, I'm going to assume that your model code is golden, and show you how I'd setup the test. I'm not sure why you need the factory to have decision making powers based on if the city exists or not. Just instantiate the city in its own factory and call the association in your test setup.

Factories

```
# factories/cities.rb
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :city do
    name  'Boston'
  end
end

# factories/users.rb
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :user do
    name  'john'
    city
  end
end
```

Test

```
describe 'blah' do
  let( :city ){ create :city }
  let( :user ){ create :user, city: city }

  it 'user should have a city' do
    expect( user.city.name ).to eq 'Boston'
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue when testing a model that belonged to another model, when a callback was creating that association.

To explain simply, let's say I have a `Book` model, and a `Page` model, with `Page belongs_to Book`, and a callback to create `Page` when a book is created.

In my factory for `Page`, I try to associate to `Book`, but by doing so I create book once, and the creation of the page itself create the same book again. By UniqueIndex condition, PostgreSQL fails.

The simplest solution in that case is to not to create `Page` when testing the Page model, but instead to simply `create(:book)` and then use `book.page`.